# Django auth ValidationError after upgrading from 1.7 to 1.8

Tags: django

I am facing a Django ValidationError after upgrading from 1.7 to 1.8. I have googled about this error, but had no luck.

error getting raised at https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django%2Fdb%2Fmodels%2Ffields%2F__init__.py#L958

any help really appreciate it.

```
Django Version: 1.8.3
    Exception Type: ValidationError
    Exception Value:    
    [u"'xyz' value must be an integer."]
```

traceback

```
 Traceback:
File "django/v1_8/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  116.                 response = middleware_method(request)
File "/local_middleware.py" in process_request
  49.     admin = request.user.groups.filter(name='admin')
File "django/v1_8/utils/functional.py" in inner
  226.             self._setup()
File "django/v1_8/utils/functional.py" in _setup
  359.         self._wrapped = self._setupfunc()
File "django/v1_8/contrib/auth/middleware.py" in <lambda>
  22.         request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))
File "django/v1_8/contrib/auth/middleware.py" in get_user
  10.         request._cached_user = auth.get_user(request)
File "django/v1_8/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in get_user
  167.         user_id = _get_user_session_key(request)
File "django/v1_8/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in _get_user_session_key
  59.     return get_user_model()._meta.pk.to_python(request.session[SESSION_KEY])
File "django/v1_8/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in to_python
  969.                 params={'value': value},

Exception Type: ValidationError at /
Exception Value: [u"'xyz' value must be an integer."]
```

detailed

```
django/v1_8/db/models/fields/__init__.py in to_python
            return value
        try:
            return int(value)
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            raise exceptions.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['invalid'],
                code='invalid',
                            params={'value': value}, ...
            )
    def validate(self, value, model_instance):
        pass
    def get_db_prep_value(self, value, connection, prepared=False):

django/v1_8/contrib/auth/middleware.py in <lambda>
    def process_request(self, request):
        assert hasattr(request, 'session'), (
            "The Django authentication middleware requires session middleware "
            "to be installed. Edit your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting to insert "
            "'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware' before "
            "'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware'."
        )
                    request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request)) ...
class SessionAuthenticationMiddleware(object):
    """
    Formerly, a middleware for invalidating a user's sessions that don't
    correspond to the user's current session authentication hash. However, it
```

Comment: Show us your models, and any non-standard part of the project. I'm fairly sure this is NOT a bug in Django.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Its a production code but i'll try to find non-standard part and keep you posted.